# Is there a bash wildcard for changing directories?

Tags: macos, bash

When using the Bash command line I can for example change to a directory using...

```
cd /volumes
```

However I would like to type...

```
cd /vol*
```

but that doesn't work.  Is there a way to navigate directories using wildcards?

Comment: It works for me

Comment: Will you say more about what you are trying to do? What behavior do you expect when there are multiple directories matching the name `/vol*`?

Comment: What would you expect `cd /vol*` to do?

Comment: As an aside you could use iTerm, it's a much better alternative to the default osx terminal. http://iterm.sourceforge.net/ It allows for tab completion and the example above should work without any problems.

Comment: @AvaGailliot bash provides tab completion regardless of the terminal program you're running. See Gordon Davisson's answer about configuring bash to ignore case for globbing & tab completion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mac OS by default uses a case insensitive file system. `cd /volumes` is equivalent to `cd /Volumes`, but bash cannot glob the `vol*`: try `cd /Vol*`

Answer (score 4):

As @William Pursell said, this is due to the folder being named /Volumes, not /volumes; the OS X filesystem is case insensitive, so it ignores the difference, but bash is case sensitive and trips over the difference.

But you can change bash's default behavior: to make it do case-insensitive expansions of file patterns, add the command `shopt -s nocaseglob` to your ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile files (it's needed in both, so the option is set in both login shells and subshells).  If you also want filename completion to work despite case mismatches, either add `set completion-ignore-case on` to your ~/.inputrc file, or add `bind "set completion-ignore-case on"` to your ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile files.

Answer (score 0):

Typing:

```
cd /vol*
```

works *just fine*.  Even if `/vol*` expands to multiple directories, `bash` will use the first one and ignore the rest.  What exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: Of course you'd normally just type `cd /vol<TAB>` and use auto completion...

Comment: @larsks I get -bash: cd: /vol*: No such file or directory when I type that in.  I am using the Terminal on Mac OS.  cd /volumes changes to that directory just fine.

Comment: @PaulR - Using Mac OS, hitting tab doesn't complete the line for me.  I have used that in the past with success on another Unix machine however.

Comment: @John: must be something funny with your bash setup then - it works for me on all current/recent versions of Mac OS X - I do seem to remember that very early versions of Mac OS X needed some tweaking to make it work though.